# Make Total Thumbnail Height Equal to Large Image Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've got four images I'm creating a Gallery with. One image is displayed at full size, while the other three images are simply cropped thumbnails.

I'm trying to work out if there's a way to have the total height of the three thumbnails equal the height of my largest image.

See the problem I'm having?

[image]

```
<div class="gallery">
    <ul class="thumbs">
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I was thinking it might be a solution some JS can solve.

I've got a demo up and running here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/hezKn

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly achieve it without JS.

Although, if you're ok with using weird selectors and styles overwritting - but i guess that can be changed if you have more freedom to alter your current HTML

Heres the fiddle just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/8tH7L/

**EDIT**

A bit more simpler, by adding some more classes

HTML:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li class="thumb thumb-hero">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0c0G0A3P1k0Q2C3F2D2j/1.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb thumb-sidebar">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/1f3F3L0A1U40213T2v2S/2.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb thumb-sidebar">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0L0B0p0Y0U2L163S400r/3.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb thumb-sidebar">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0r1G3Z432A0Y2r0w2X0f/4.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbs {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.thumb-hero {
    float:right;
    width:50%;    
}

.thumb-sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:21.5%; /*firebuged it*/
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.thumb-sidebar img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**updated fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/8tH7L/2/

**further info**

figuring out `padding-bottom` value of `.thumb-sidebar`

from the code - image size is 800x1029.

to arrange 3 images next to main image means each sidebar image height must be `1029/3 = 343px` high i.e, each sidebar image size must be `800x343`

Now because whole section is going to be fluid ( unless otherwise ) fluid padding-bottom should be `( 343 [ sidebar image height ] / 1600 [ whole thumbnail section width which is 800 * 2 ] ) * 100 [ percentage ]` and that comes to `21.4375%`

*note:* instead of doing the math, its much easier to pop open developer toolbar and fiddle with padding-bottom value until you get the desired result

Comment: Altering the current HTML wouldn't be the worse thing. Do you recommend doing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, with altering markup i meant adding some more presentational classes which will reduce the use of sibling selectors ```.thumb + .thumb``` etc. Anyway, updated my answer with the new fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/8tH7L/2/ ) -cheers

Comment: That `height: 0;` hack works out great! Can you let me know how you're generating those percentages in Firebug? Thanks! Accepted answer.

Comment: Hey man, just the usual firebug -> inspect any of the ```.thumb-sidebar``` -> styles tab -> fiddle with ```padding-bottom``` until you get the desired result. Updated my answer with details about math involved

Answer (score 0):

chnage your css code:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JIAhG

you can can use js to make it dynamic, but this will do the jab